# Compiling Python 3.4/5 fails with segmentation fault on RedHat 6.4

Tags: python, redhat

I try to compile a new Python 3.x version on a Redhat 6.4 machine. In this example i use 3.5.1.

GCC is gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC).

```
./configure --prefix=/data/tools/python3
```

works fine, but make fails:

```
make
gcc -pthread -fPIC -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv   -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/libffi/include -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/libffi -I/cs/san_development/download/py3/Python-3.5.1/Modules/_ctypes/libffi/src -I./Include -I. -IInclude -I/usr/local/include -I/cs/san_development/download/py3/Python-3.5.1/Include -I/cs/san_development/download/py3/Python-3.5.1 -c /cs/san_development/download/py3/Python-3.5.1/Modules/_ctypes/libffi/src/x86/sysv.S -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/cs/san_development/download/py3/Python-3.5.1/Modules/_ctypes/libffi/src/x86/sysv.o -Wall -fexceptions
gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/cs/san_development/download/py3/Python-3.5.1/Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/cs/san_development/download/py3/Python-3.5.1/Modules/_ctypes/callbacks.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/cs/san_development/download/py3/Python-3.5.1/Modules/_ctypes/callproc.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/cs/san_development/download/py3/Python-3.5.1/Modules/_ctypes/stgdict.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/cs/san_development/download/py3/Python-3.5.1/Modules/_ctypes/cfield.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/cs/san_development/download/py3/Python-3.5.1/Modules/_ctypes/libffi/src/prep_cif.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/cs/san_development/download/py3/Python-3.5.1/Modules/_ctypes/libffi/src/closures.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/cs/san_development/download/py3/Python-3.5.1/Modules/_ctypes/libffi/src/x86/ffi64.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/cs/san_development/download/py3/Python-3.5.1/Modules/_ctypes/libffi/src/x86/unix64.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/cs/san_development/download/py3/Python-3.5.1/Modules/_ctypes/libffi/src/x86/ffi.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/cs/san_development/download/py3/Python-3.5.1/Modules/_ctypes/libffi/src/x86/sysv.o -L/data/tools/python3/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/_ctypes.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/bin/sh: line 6:  4791 Segmentation fault      CC='gcc -pthread' LDSHARED='gcc -pthread -shared  ' OPT='-DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes' _TCLTK_INCLUDES='' _TCLTK_LIBS='' ./python -E ./setup.py $quiet build
make: *** [sharedmods] Error 139
```

A single execution of the last command shows:

```
CC='gcc -pthread' LDSHARED='gcc -pthread -shared  ' OPT='-DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes' _TCLTK_INCLUDES='' _TCLTK_LIBS='' ./python -E ./setup.py $quiet build
running build
running build_ext
Segmentation fault
```

When I remove the $quiet and add -v to python I get:

```
.....
import '_csv' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x7fc89dbfe8d0>
# extension module '_posixsubprocess' loaded from 'build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/_posixsubprocess.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
# extension module '_posixsubprocess' executed from 'build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/_posixsubprocess.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
import '_posixsubprocess' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x7fc89dbfe978>
# extension module '_socket' loaded from 'build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/_socket.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
# extension module '_socket' executed from 'build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/_socket.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
import '_socket' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x7fc89dbfec50>
Segmentation fault
```

But that doesn't really tell my anything :-)

I think I have all the dependencies installed

I also changed -O3 to -O2 -Os or even -O0 but nothing helped.

Any help would be appreciated.
Daniel

BTW, is my first post on stackoverflow, hope I didn't make to much mistakes...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the RH Software Collection version: http://developers.redhat.com/products/softwarecollections/get-started-rhel6-python/

This doc is for 3.4, but there's a 3.5 version too.